# Perturbing a regular submanifold to ensure submersion.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Suppose $M$ is a regular compact submanifold with boundary of dimension $n$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}\smallsetminus 0$, and assume that for each $v\in S^n$ the ray emanating from $v$ intersects $M$ in at most one point. Denote by $S$ the subset of $S^{n}$ where this happens. The surjective submersion $r: \mathbb R^{n+1}\smallsetminus 0\longrightarrow S^n$ restricts to a bijection $r : M\longrightarrow S$.

Note that $\ker r_{p,\ast}=\langle p\rangle$ intersects $M$ at one point, but it can happen that $\langle p\rangle \subseteq T_pM$ (for example, draw a projected $x\mapsto x^3$ around $S^1$). However, in the one dimensional case, there are only finitely many such points where this fails, and one can perturb $M$ by a diffeomorphism in a neighbourhood of such points to preserve all hypothesis and guarantee that $r$ restricts to a submersion $r: M\longrightarrow S$ which must then be a diffeomorphism.

Suppose now that $n>1$. One can mimic the above to obtain a submanifold $M$ where the points where $\langle p\rangle \subseteq T_pM$ form a $n-1$ dimensional submanifold in $S^n$. For example, by extending the previous example in higher dimensions, one can produce a circle inside $S^2$, etc.

Can one in general modify $M$ slightly by a diffeomorphism so that $\langle p\rangle + T_p M =T_p\mathbb R^{n+1}$?

Comment: You should clarify your question: Are you trying to perturb your submanifold $M$ to $M'$ so that the projection $r|M'$ is a diffeomorphism to its image? Or you are trying to get this just at one point $p\in M$? For the former question the trouble is that the singular set of a smooth injective map $M\to S^n$ need not be a submanifold and can have a very complicated structure. Another thing to worry about is existence of injective smooth maps which cannot be approximated by local diffeomorphisms (e.g. for exotic spheres).

Comment: I want to perturb M by a diffeomorphism so that r is a submersion,  more precisely so that the transversality condition holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but an extended comment. Start with the case $n=1$ when $M$ is diffeomorphic to $[0,1]$. Via polar coordinates, the problem becomes the one about smooth curves in $R^2$ which are graphs of continuous monotonic functions $f: [a,b]\to R$: The projection $r$ corresponds to the projection to the $y$-axis. Note that $f$ itself need not be smooth as the tangent to the graph could be vertical. In any case, a continuous monotonic function can indeed be approximated by smooth monotonic functions with nonvanishing derivatives and hence, the projections from their graphs to the $y$-axis become submersions. However, the original function $f$ can have an arbitrary measure zero Cantor set $C$ as the set of its critical points, i.e. points where $f'(x)=0$. Thus, the claim you make about finiteness of the set of points in $M$ where $dr=0$ is false.

The situation becomes much more complex in higher dimensions. I will think in terms of perturbing an injective smooth map $r: M^n\to N^n$ (where in your case $N^n=S^n$). I see no way to find a perturbation such that the critical set of the perturbed map is a submanifold and the new map is still 1-1. Once you loose injectivity, you easily get a "fold singularity" which, in turn, cannot be perturbed away. A cautionary example is the one of Milnor's exotic spheres $\Sigma^n$ which admit smooth injective maps $\Sigma^n\to S^n$. However, unlike in your case, the derivative vanishes identically at a point in these examples.

On the other hand, once you have a smooth injective map $f: M^n\to N^n$ whose derivative has rank $\ge n-1$ evereywhere and the singular set is a codimension 1 submanifold, then $f$ can be approximated by immersions.

Comment: It is not clear to me how regularity of the submanifold and compactness are not violated by infinitely many critical points. Shouldn't things go awry if we look at an accumulation point of these points?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Graph of a smooth function is always regular. The examples are quite simple: Use the fact that for each closed subset $C\subset R^n$ there is a smooth nonnegative function whose zero set is exactly $C$. Now integrate this function ($n=1$).

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks.